# Ho to tell if my comp has incompatible GPU?

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, gpu

Accordingly to [this website](http://www.pc-specs.com/mobo/GigaByte/Gigabyte_GA-X58-USB3/757/Compatible_GPUs%22this%20website%22), my computer is running a non compatible GPU, exactly the GeForce 750 which is not in the list, since it is freezing and I have already tested other issues such as drivers and RAM I wanted to replace the GPU and noticed, quite surprisingly that the model 690 is quite more expensive than another 750 which is supposed to be newer and more performant.

Now my doubt is that the 700 serie is a faulty one, this could explain the lack of the serie in the above link and the incredible price discrepancy.

Back to my question, am I using an incompatible GPU?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, incompatible *with your mainboard*, then yes, it's incompatible, at least officially. The manufacturer does not list your GPU model as compatible so don't expect any support from there.
You could try to play with BIOS-level PCI settings but it is not likely things will ever be as stable as you want.
It looks like Gigabyte introduced the GA-X58-USB3 mainboard in 2010 whereas Nvidia released the GeForce 7xx series in 2014. That is four years later! Call it planned obsolence or whatever you like but Gigabyte could not know four years in advance what hardware Nvidia would bring. Hardware demands are probably so different that no BIOS update could easily solve the discrepancy.

Instead of buying an older GPU just to be compatible to the mainboard, why don't you consider replacing the mainboard instead?

Comment: Just to be clear; since it was a tech shop who suggested me to replace an older card with the 750 was he supposed to know it was not compatible with my motherboard?

Comment: for example for [this website](https://pcpartpicker.com/products/video-card/#m=252) neither the 690 is compatible. While for [this other](http://www.userbenchmark.com/System/Gigabyte-GA-X58-USB3/729) the 760 is compatible. Is it opinionated or we have official data?

Comment: Well, if Gigabyte do not list the Geforce 700 series as compatible on their site dedicated to your mainboard, it's official, at least that's what I thought. Sites dedicated to present gamer systems will test a certain combination of hardware, or even multiple variations. If their result is compatible or incompatible, I would give that more credit than the manufacturer's. A shop could be blamed for a false info but how are they supposed to keep up with all developments and discontinued products? So if you want something that works, use hardware that has been tested in combination.

Comment: I looked up on Gigabyte website for X58-USB3 but it doesn't list compative GPU only ram and processors, where did you find this information?

Comment: It's in the same web site you stated in your first post. It clearly has GPU compatibility infos. That's what we discuss here in the first place, right?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean, I found out that the website in question is totally missing 700 serie from its database, it is not a reliable audit then.